# Let $u(x,y) = x^2 + 2axy + by^2$, where $a$ and $b$ are real, when is $u$ the real part of an analytic function and what's the imaginary part?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does my approach here seem agreeable?

(Revised) Attempt:

If $u$ is the real portion of an analytic function in the complex plane, it must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, we have 
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x + 2ay = y_v $$
and
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 2by + 2ax = -v_x.$$

By the first of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, we have 
$$ v = \int \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} dy + f(x) 
= \int (2x+2ay) dy + f(x)
= 2xy + ay^2 + f(x).$$

for some function $f(x)$.

Differentiate with respect to $x$ yields
$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 2y + f'(x) .$$

By the second of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, we get
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= -2ax - 2by - 2y \\
f(x) &= -ax^2 - 2bxy - 2xy
\end{align*}

Hence,

$$ v = ay^2 -2bxy - ax^2.$$

Now, we differentiate $v$ with respect to $x,y$ to get
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} &= -2ax -2by \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} &=  2ay - 2bx .
\end{align*}
Notice
$$-(-2ax -2by) = 2ax + 2by$$
so $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ for all values of $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Since $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ must hold, we can see that the equality
$$2ay - 2bx = 2ay + 2x$$
holds for all values of $a$ and $b=-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for $a$ to be $0$.  Your mistake is that your $C$'s don't really have to be constant: integrating a function of $x$ and $y$ with respect to $x$, say, the "constant of integration" can be a function of $y$.

Hint: the real part of an analytic function is a harmonic function.

Comment: Robert, your comments are most helpful. I think I have my solution. Can you comment on it? (I've revised my original post)